# Generating C# classes from JSON key value pair

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have been searching for a solution for a few hours now but haven't found anything that explains my problem. I am an absolute beginner in C# and I need help converting this JSON into C# classes, particularly the `fields` object that has a key value pair.

Here is what the JSON looks like:

```
[
 {
   "creationTimestamp": 1485384284523,
   "lastUpdatedTimestamp": 1485384699883,
   "lastStageChangeTimestamp": 1485384284523,
   "fields": {
       "key1": "val1",
       "key2": "val2"
    }
 }
]
```

Any tips on how to approach this problem would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Meaning the key value pairs in fields is dynamic?

Comment: Yes, they are both dynamic

Comment: Make `fields` be a `Dictionary<string, string>`.  Most JSON serializers support this.  See [How can I deserialize JSON to a simple Dictionary<string,string> in ASP.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1207731/3744182).

Comment: Copy your Json in the clipboard ,then on Visual Studio Edit->Paste Special -> Paste Json as Classess

Answer (score 1):

Create a class to hold the data.

Using a tool like http://jsonutils.com/ you can paste the json and get back

```
public class Fields
{
    public string key1 { get; set; }
    public string key2 { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public long creationTimestamp { get; set; }
    public long lastUpdatedTimestamp { get; set; }
    public long lastStageChangeTimestamp { get; set; }
    public Fields fields { get; set; }
}
```

The Json.Net library would allow you to desrialize the json into the above classes.

```
var models = JsonConvert.DesrializeObject<RootObject[]>(json);

var val1 = models[0].key1;
var val2 = models[0].key2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please Use Dictionary datatype for fields property
public class RootObject
{
 public long creationTimestamp { get; set; }
 public long lastUpdatedTimestamp { get; set; }
 public long lastStageChangeTimestamp { get; set; }
 public Dictionary<string,string> fields { get; set; }
}
```